# Prove that $[K:F]\leq 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a fied, $x^4+1\in F[x]$ and K its splitting fied. Prove that $[K:F]\leq 4$. I have no ideas. Help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Proof sketch: Start with the case you're probably most familiar with: $F=\Bbb Q$. How does $x^4+1$ factor over the reals? What degree extension of $\Bbb Q$ does that factorisation require? Once you have that extension, show that extending by one of the roots of one of the factors automatically gives you the remaining three roots.

Now note that nothing you did here really required $\Bbb Q$ specifically (apart from knowing that each step actually required an extension), and may be done in general.